# Is Eclipse and Android SDK (Simulator) is faster on Windows or Mac machine?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have 2 machines, one runs Windows 7 and another Mac. Hardware config is almost the same in the two, 2.4 with 4G RAM.

I notice the android simulator is slow in Windows 7, whould it run faster if I intsall Eclipse and Android SDK on the Mac machine?

what about Eclipse and Android SDK in general?

Comment: The speed of the simulator is only one factor when considering whether it is "faster to develop". You should also consider what useful third party development tools are available on that platform, keyboard shortcuts, UI design that improves productivity, your familiarity with the platform, etc... Are you only interested in the speed of the simulator, and if so, could you please reword your question to make that clear?

Comment: I meant simulator + Eclipse + Android SDK as whole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `android device` is better option that simulator it is much much faster than simulator. If you are planning for serious development then you should buy one android device.

Comment: I'd certainly agree with this as well.  Although sometimes I like to use the emulator to test how well my apps will run on slower hardware (most of devices I have are newer/faster).  I figure if my app runs well on the sluggish emulator, then it'll run well on just about any device :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a 13" Macbook pro (2010 model, 2.4ghz, 4 gig ram) and the emulator is pretty slow on it... I tend to develop mostly on my Linux desktop, which is 2.4ghz machine as well, and while the emulator is slow it's still MUCH faster than the Mac.   Eclipse runs about the same on both... actually the Mac might even be slight faster since it has a SSD.

It's been my experience from watching other Macs run the emulator that the emulator is just slow on Mac :(

I know Google recently updated the the ADK to include speed improvements for the emulator, but I haven't tried that yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try running it on mac, I did the same and found that the emulator runs much faster on mac, as compared to windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have a windows 7 laptop 2 yrs old (8GB, i5) and 15inch MacBook pro 2012 (16GB, i7). I might also note that I am primarily a .NET developer, so I should be bias towards OSX.

I found that running the emulator and the ide on a mac runs faster than windows.  I know the mac is considerably faster than my windows box but the difference in the speed of eclipse/emulator doesn't jive. The emulator runs smoother.  Eclipse compiles faster on my Mac.  The debugger settles/attached to hardware devices quicker.

My experience developing with Eclipse (Android SDK) is much more pleasant on the Mac than windows

Answer (score 0):

I develop primarily on a desktop running Windows 8 since most of our apps are written in C#, I always found debugging painful on both a Samsung S3 and using the emulator.

I had read about using Intel HAXM which is available in the Android SDK Downloader, but never enabled it since I use Hyper-V on my desktop as well.

Fast forward, I'm now using a MacBook Pro because of needing to do iPhone development as well. I installed HAXM on the MacBook, and it made the x86 Android emulator run extremely fast.

TLDR: Install Intel HAXM on a machine with a modern CPU and you'll find running apps on your machine significantly faster.

If you do have Hyper V installed, you can disable it temporarily by creating a boot entry that causes Windows to boot with it disabled.